# How to save Python 1D, 2D or 3D NumpPy array into MATLAB .mat

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, file-io, scipy

Python's SciPy package has a function that saves Python variable into MATLAB's `.mat` file
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html
However, the documentation lacks examples, and I don't know what is the dictionary of variables it wants as an input.

Say I have a 2D NumPy array `A` and a 3D NumPy array `B`, how do I save them into a `.mat` file called `my_arrays.mat`?

Can I save multiple variables in `.mat` or do I need a file to each variable?

How to read `.mat` files into Python and how do I know to reach variables they have been loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples for saving and loading

```
import scipy.io as sio

# dummy data
A = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
B = np.random.randint(0,10,100)

# collect arrays in dictionary
savedict = {
    'A' : A,
    'B' : B,
}

# save to disk
sio.savemat('my_arrays.mat', savedict)

#load from disk
data = sio.loadmat('my_arrays.mat')

# alternative way to load from disk:
data = {}
sio.loadmat('my_arrays.mat', mdict=data)
```